# Why is my bar graph not stretching according to the data i received?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

[image: This is my output]

Why does my Bar Graph is not stretching even though I'm sending the data properly? I tried to change the height of it, but the maximum value shows is only 100, but when I hover the mouse to specific bar, it shows different value?

```
{id: '26', name: 'CAHS 2022-2023 1st Semester', coursecount: '112'},
{id: '32', name: 'CASE 2022-2023 1st Semester', coursecount: '326'},
{id: '36', name: 'CBMA 2022-2023 1st Semester', coursecount: '204'},
{id: '42', name: 'CEIS 2022-2023 1st Semester', coursecount: '114'},
{id: '47', name: 'CHTM 2022-2023 1st Semester', coursecount: '153'},
{id: '52', name: 'CMT 2022-2023 1st Semester', coursecount: '170'},
{id: '71', name: 'SHS 2022-2023 1st Semester', coursecount: '98'}
```

This is my Barchart.js

```
const BarGraphUsageStudents = ({data}) => {

   return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
    <BarChart
      width={500}
      height={300}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5,
      }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <XAxis dataKey="name" />
      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <Bar dataKey="coursecount" fill="#69e141" />
    </BarChart>
  </ResponsiveContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: try removing  '<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">' wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the **`string`** value in the `coursecount`.

Try to change all your `coursecount` to the **`number`** type or if you can't, you can write a map on your `data` like this:

```js
data={data.map(item => ({ ...item, coursecount: Number(item.coursecount) }))}
```

[**Online demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-water-58zyv4?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is due to width and height given in `ResponsiveContainer`, they are 100% of parent and thus it is affected by the parent container, also the string type of `coursecount`.

add a `div` above `ResponsiveContainer` and give height to that div, by doing this , your chart will be responsive as well (try resizing), and change type of `coursecount`

```
const BarGraphUsageStudents = ({data}) => {

   return (
 <div style={{"height":"500px"}}>
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
    <BarChart
      width={500}
      height={300}
      data={data.map(item => ({ ...item, coursecount: 
         Number(item.coursecount) }))}        
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5,
      }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <XAxis dataKey="name" />
      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <Bar dataKey="coursecount" fill="#69e141" />
    </BarChart>
  </ResponsiveContainer>
</div>  
    );
}
```